# How to fade a div after specific scroll

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a div which floats on top after people scroll down the head part like google+ homepage and Facebook's profile page. I am trying to use JavaScript. So please help me with it.

I have tried this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
         $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
     } else {
         $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
     }
 });
```

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: I used these code but it wasn't helpful.

$(window).scroll(function(){       if($(window).scrollTop ()>100){          $("#theDiv").fadeIn();       }else{          $("#theDiv").fadeOut ();       } });

Comment: if my answer was what you were looking for please mark the question answered by my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i think you could have finished the question yourself with a bit more effort, here a jsFiddle in which you code was made working.

http://jsfiddle.net/AfYfE/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
        $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
    } else {
       $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

this will  make the div dissapear when you scroll down.

Dont forget to include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library if you are using these selectors and functions